# Script/command to copy internal IP address directly into clipboard

Tags: shell, clipboard

I am currently using an alias for ifconfig as `iip="ifconfig | grep 'broadcast\|wlan\|eth0'"` which simply shows me the lines containing IP address for ethernet and wireless network adapter. Every time I need internal/private IP, I run this simple alias. But then I have to copy the IP address manually.

Is there any command which would copy the internal/private IP address directly into the clipboard for use (the command would recognize an IP address which is in format `*.*.*.*` where if value of any `*` is 255 (netmask or broadcast address) then do not copy that pattern, else copy the pattern into clipboard)

**Edit**: I'm talking about the buffer that holds the copied value in memory

Comment: is this a GUI clipboard you're talking about?

Comment: @JeffSchaller no

Comment: I also found that we can also use `xclip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool like sed or awk to extract the part of the output you want. Then use [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) ([`pbcopy`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html) on macOS) to copy that to the clipboard.

Note that the interface name is not on the same line as the IP address, so filtering has to take multiple lines into account.

```
ifconfig | awk '
    /^[^ ]/ {interface = $1}
    $1=="inet" && interface ~ /^(broadcast|wlan|eth0)$/ {sub(/^addr:/, "", $2); print $2}
' | xsel -b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the output into a file and use the command line tool xsel to share terminal and GUI clipboard. You could set it into a script that will do the work for you.

http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/

Comment: If this works, it would not copy the IP address, this copies the whole output. I want to be able to sort out the `*.*.*.*` pattern to copy